# Firebase verifyIdToken "auth/argument-error" (ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I rarely require to ask a question here but I can't figure out what is going on with my code.

I have a wab app where users login with firebase auth and a server that verify tokenId and retrieve the BDD user. But suddenly when i try to call verifyIdToken(token) with a valid token in development (local) mode im geting an error:

```
async login(id_token) {
    return await auth.verifyIdToken(id_token)
}

06/12/2023 16:26:59 [User           ] [?] login(token = eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIs[...]) : error -> FirebaseAuthError: Error while making request: connect ETIMEDOUT 2a00:1450:4007:80b::200a:443.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (D:\Projects\nexus-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (D:\Projects\nexus-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (D:\Projects\nexus-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:149:16)
    at FirebaseTokenVerifier.mapJwtErrorToAuthError (D:\Projects\nexus-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\token-verifier.js:281:16)
    at D:\Projects\nexus-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\token-verifier.js:253:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.login (file:///D:/Projects/nexus-server/api/firebase/index.js:44:20)
    at async Object.login (file:///D:/Projects/nexus-server/repository/userRepository.js:241:26)
    at async Socket.<anonymous> (file:///D:/Projects/nexus-server/server.js:99:47) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'auth/argument-error',
    message: 'Error while making request: connect ETIMEDOUT 2a00:1450:4007:80b::200a:443.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'auth'
}
```

Does anyone have a clue on whats wrong with that ? I precise that a did not change any part of the code and the production live work well.

I tried to find a solution an internet, to update or rétrograde packages, I don't know what I can do more on that but this code worked during month and I did not change anything...